# Dold Kan correspondence is an adjunction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am trying to work out exercise 8.4.2 from [Weibel's Simplicial Methods in Homological Algebra](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug//otherpapers/weibel-hom.pdf). That is, I want to show that the Dold Kan equivalence in fact is an adjoint equivalence. I wanted to check whether my reasoning is correct or not.

The relevant functors are summarized the following. The normalized Moore functor $N:\mathcal{sAb}\to \mathcal{Ch}_{+}$ mapping a simplicial abelian group $A_\bullet$ to the chain complex with in degree $n$ the quotient $A_n/DA_n$, where $DA_n$ is given by the degenerate $n$-simplices in $A_\bullet$. Its inverse functor $\Gamma$ maps a chain complex $C$ to the simplicial abelian group which in degree $n$ is given by $$\bigoplus_{n\twoheadrightarrow k} C_k.$$

The natural isomorphism $\eta:id \to N\Gamma $ on component $C$ is the chain complex morphism which in degree $n$ is defined by the following composition $$C_n \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{n\twoheadrightarrow k} C_k \to  \bigoplus_{n\twoheadrightarrow k} C_k/\bigoplus_{n\twoheadrightarrow k, k\neq n} C_k\to C_n      $$where the last map is an isomorphism. This map is an isomorphism on $C_n$, however it seems to me that I cannot say that this map *really* is the identity.

The map $\epsilon:\Gamma N\to id$ is given on component $A_\bullet$ by first using that $(NA_\bullet)_n$ is isomorphic to the intersection $$\bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1} \ker(d_i)\subset A_n$$ and then mapping $x_\sigma$ in $\bigoplus_{n\twoheadrightarrow k} C_k$, where $\sigma$ denotes a surjection $[n]\to [k]$ to the $\sigma^*(x)$ in $A_n$.

To show that these two natural transformations give $N$ and $\Gamma$ the structure of an adjoint, we want to show that the triangle identities $\epsilon \Gamma \circ \Gamma \eta=id$ and $N\epsilon \circ \eta N=id$ are satisfied. However, I cannot see why this should necessarily hold. There are many isomorphisms involved in the construction, and although it is clear that these identities hold up to some canonical isomorphism, I dont see why they should exactly be the same. Perhaps I'm overthinking things, or perhaps I'm missing out on some part of the theory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a general fact that any equivalence of categories can be "improved" to an adjoint equivalence, albeit by replacing some of the data. If you have explicitly constructed all the natural transformations required it can be useful to check that they are "already correct", but if some are inexplicit then you may as well apply the general fact and replace them with the "correct" ones.

Comment: This is just a remark: If there is in fact an adjoint to $N$, call it $G$. Then $G(C)_n= \operatorname{Hom}_{sAb}(\mathbb Z[\Delta[n]],G(C))=\operatorname{Hom}_{Ch}(N \mathbb Z[\Delta[n]],C)$ by the yoneda lemma. Perhaps its easier to verify that at each step, this agrees with the construction of $\Gamma$ for each $n$

Comment: @ZhenLin so this means that I just can state that $N$ and $\Gamma$ are adjoints given the fact that they are equivalences? And that in this case the improved $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ only differ a very little bit with the ones I described above?

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, that is interesting to consider too. In fact I believe that this corresponds with the construction Kan uses in his proof. So indeed, showing that $G(C)$ and $\Gamma(C)$ are isomorphic immediately shows they are adjoints, and vice versa, showing that $N\dashv \Gamma$ makes sure that the construction above corresponds to Kan's.